# Compiling Qt applications from command-line in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, command-line, sdk

I downloaded Qt SDK and set up paths for qmake etc commands. Now I'm trying to compile "Hello World" program from command-line but don't know how to do that in Windows.

In Linux, it's very simple: qmake -project; qmake; make;

In Windows I tried: qmake -project; qmake; mingw32-make;
mingw32-make returns: "Nothing to be done for first"

Source code which I would like to compile is here:

```
#include <QtGui>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle("Hello World!");
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I know that I could use Qt Creator IDE but I would like to know how to compile Qt programs in command-line.

Anybody have experiences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nothing to be done" can indicate that everything was already compiled.

You can run `mingw32-make clean` and then `mingw32-make` again to check if that's the case.

Also check that the .pro file generated by `qmake -project` does list your .cpp file in the `SOURCES` variable.

Comment: .pro file is almost empty. It has only template variable.

Comment: @Karmo Did you run `qmake -project` in the same directory where the .cpp file is ? Are you using the Qt Command Prompt (that was created in the Start Menu, under QtSDK/Desktop) ?